# Python - how to entirely stop a function if criteria is not met?

Tags: python, if-statement, pathlib, tomlkit

I have these two functions. The first one gets a file path ensures the file exists.
The second function is intended to check that a table exists in a toml file and then ensure three values exist and are not `None` or `''`

I am wondering how I can make it completely fail if any the table `default` or any of the three values don't exist.

```
def get_source_path(env_var: str, default_path: str) -> str:
    final_path = Path(os.getenv(env_var, default_path)).expanduser().resolve()
    if not final_path.is_file():
        raise FileNotFoundError(f'File {final_path} does not exist')
    return final_path
    

def check_toml():
    toml_dict = tomlkit.loads(Path(get_source_path('CONFIG_PATH', const.D_CONFIG_PATH)).read_text())
    if dd := toml_dict.get('default'):
        for key in 'conf_path', 'prefix', 'suffix':
            if not dd.get(key):
                print(f'Expected key "{key}" is missing')
    else:
        print('Toml file missing default table')
    return toml_dict
```

Basically, I want the second function to fail and tell either default is missing or one of the three values are missing - otherwise return `toml_dict`.

The toml file looks like

```
[default]
conf_path = "d"
prefix = "p"
suffix = "s"
```

Edit;

I think my best bet may be to raise a keyerror. But still thinking on best how.

Comment: `return` and `raise` will both terminate a function immediately.

Comment: If I simply change the print to a return - I would only ever get the first missing key. So say prefix and suffix were both missing. I would only be told prefix was missing. That is part of what I am trying to navigate. I could probably yield and loop but do I really need to do all of that?

Comment: You can use a boolean to track if you've seen an error while parsing. Then at the end of the function you can return the dict if the boolean is false or raise an exception if it's true.

Comment: I'd need to add the missing key messages to a list if I go the boolean route right? I was thinking something similar but use a dataclass. But in the end - to `return` all missing keys, I'd need to add them to a list right? So instead of this `print(f'Expected key "{key}" is missing')` - add them to a list.